# Centering Buttons in XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So I'm working on this app and am trying to center two buttons below an edit text but I cannot get anything to work. I've tried layout gravity center to no avail.

Heres a pic of my app

[image: app screen]

As you see on the screnshot the buttons are not centered. Also, I'm trying to fix the textbox, In the pic you can see that the text goes all the way to the edge of the edit text box.

heres my xml layout. I'm sure it's not the most efficient design if someone has any input on how to make it better I would appreciate that. I'm very new to xml.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.BirdsboroClimbing.RouteDetails">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:text="Route Climbed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/routeCheckBox"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <CheckBox
            android:text="Show Note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/noteCheckBox"
            android:gravity="center"
             />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="eg. fell at third clip etc..."
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
            android:layout_below="@id/routeCheckBox"
            android:background="@drawable/note_background"
            />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/noteEditText"
            android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"

            >
            <Button android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="Save"
                android:id="@+id/saveButto"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />

            <Button android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="Delete"
                android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonLayout"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/routeImage"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and here the xml file for my edittext background

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#2f6699" />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
```

Sorry for the size of the image. I wanted to make sure you guys could see how the text overlaps the edittext edges.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you tried to give gravity="center" (not layout_gravity) to the Linear Layout with ID buttonLayout ?

Comment: That did it! I was trying it on the individual buttons before. I assumed it was something simple I overlooked. thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Another way to do it would have been to make the LinearLayout they're in wrap_content, and use layout_alignCenterHorizontal on it

Comment: For the problem with the Textview, add `android:padding` or if you want to add the padding individual `android:paddingTop`  `android:paddingLeft` `android:paddingRight` and `android:paddingBottom` :)

Comment: That worked also!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/routeCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Route Climbed"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/noteCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Show Note"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/routeCheckBox"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sadsmiley"
            android:hint="eg. fell at third clip etc..."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"

            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/noteEditText"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"

            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButto"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:text="Save"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:text="Delete"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonLayout"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/routeImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```